# How to pass current iteration variable to method?

Tags: graphql

How do I pass the `applicationId` from the root of this query to the `timeSlicedEvents` method?

I can't seem to find any GraphQL terminology for this, but I'm probably searching for the wrong terms. I'm assuming there is a directive of some sort?

```
  allApplications(onlyMonitored: false) {
    applicationId
    name
    timeSlicedEvents(duration: 1800, slices: 80, applicationId: ??) {
      sliceId
      warningCount
      failureCount
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You declare a parameter at the root of your query. Very unintuitive since I have no intention of passing that myself. I assume the server implementation of the GraphQL spec is somehow doing the magic of iterating over the rows from `allApplications` and then calling the `timeSlicedEvents` using the current iteration's value.

```
query allTheThings($applicationId: Int) {
  allApplications {
    applicationId
    name
    timeSlicedEvents(duration: 2300, slices: 80, applicationId: $applicationId) {
      sliceId
      warningCount
      failureCount
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: no magic, simple assignment ... check if this value is not available in the parent (1st resolver arg), no variable passing required in this case - or make sure it's always available, even when not returned (application resolver)